# Insert Legend for Specific Geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm mapping some municipalities for the State of Minas Gerais/Brazil and so far I was able to plot it as I want it. Besides the geometry and data used, I've been tring to highlight for a few of then - I did it using geom_point.

However, I want to add a legend for this group of municipalities...I tried everything and couldn't find a way.

[Maps image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMCtZ.png)

```
m1 <- ggplot2::ggplot() +
                  #data.frame mun2 with geom for all municipalities
                  geom_sf(data = mun2, mapping = aes(fill = faixa_PIBpc)) +
                  # adding geom_points for a few municipalities, data.frame coda
                  geom_point(data = coda, aes(X, Y), colour = "darkred", shape =17, size = 1.2) +
                  labs(title = "PIB Per Capita",
                  subtitle = "Dados 2018 (R$ 2020)",
                  fill = "Decil de PIB per Capita",
                  caption = "Fonte: Elaboração própria. Dados: IBGE.") +
                  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.0)) +
                  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.0)) 



m1 +  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

Could you guys help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: If you want a legend you have to map on the color aesthetic, i.,e. move color= "darkred" inside aes(). To set the color and labels you could make use of scale_color_identity.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Trying to replace title of the second legend, but it's much better now, thanks a lot.